# How to get the invitation_id from a github invitation

Tags: api, curl, github-api, httr, rcurl

I'm using the github api to accept and list arepository invitataion. I'm using this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#invitations).
Nevertheless I couldn't figure out from where I can get the invitation_id to add it to the request to accept the repository invitation as follows `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/invitations/{invitation_id}`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Github docs, the admin needs to add a collaborator to the repository : https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#add-a-repository-collaborator

Then you get an invitation id that you can use.
The admin can also read out all invitation ids that currently exist: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#invitations

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes after adding  a collaborator and listing the invitations I get a Json like in [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-invitations). Where's the invitation_id in here?